# How to set paramenters in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

This query always return all node with any `proviName`

```
@Query("START n=node:__types__(className='Province') WHERE n.name =~'.*{0}.*' RETURN n")
    List<Province> findEntitybyname(String proviName);
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of a string or regexp no parameter substitution is performed, pass in your query as a string:

```
@Query("START n=node:__types__(className='Province') WHERE n.name =~ {0} RETURN n")
List<Province> findEntitybyname(String proviName);

repo.findEntitybyname('.*"+proviName+".*');
```